# php, exporting to .csv charset encoding issue

Tags: php, mysql, csv, joomla, joomla2.5

i have problem when i want to export data from database as CSV.

```
$data =new stdClass();
$data->id = NULL;
$data->data = serialize($data_to_store);
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->insertObject('#__hollow', $data, 'id');
```

the code above is to save data from `html` form.

```
$query->select('p.data');
$query->from('`#__hollow` AS p');
```

when i echo `p.data` everything is ok but when i insert it to .csv all looks messy.
Now the most important part of code where is error but don't know where

```
foreach ($this->data as $key => $question) {
     $CSV[] = utf8_decode($question->question_name) . $this->delimiter . implode($this->delimiter, $question->question_answers);
}
return implode("\n", $CSV);
```

and :

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
```

i tryed do switch `utf8_decode` and `utf8_encode` but it's not working.
Sorry for my poor english.
If u can point me where i make mistake i would be gratefull.

Comment: i believe he refers to charset encoding.

Comment: `Znam i stosuj? w pracy przepisy bhp obowi?zuj?ce w s?u?bie zdrowia
` this is one line from export

Comment: which program do you use to open CSV? Microsoft Excel? Windows standard encoding suits best for excel (Windows cp1251 in case of cyrilic). Try opening the document with good text editor like Notepad++ and check the text formatting and encoding.

Comment: Why not use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html)?

Comment: by removing `utf8_decode` it show correctly in notepad ++